# Badges not getting listed/searched under the 'All' tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Under the *'Activity'* tab of my *'Profile'*, in the *'Badges'* section, clicking the 'Settings' icon (which lets one *'Choose which badge to track'*) opens a window like the following:

[image]

Now, if I search for the string `"rev"`, I see only *'Custodian'* and *'Revival'* badges under the *'All'* tab. Where is *'Reversal'*?

[image]

Similarly, if I type the complete name (`"reversal"`), the search results are empty. Same happens for the query `"unsung hero"`.

Comment: reversal and unsung hero badges are not trackable or chase-able they are acquired when certain conditions met which is spontaneous.

Comment: Those badges are not in the list because they are not trackable. This is by design.

Comment: Ah, so only "trackable" badges are listed there. Got it. Thanks.